# How update Data from mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

So I try to update data from input type, but when i click update button the data wont change, here's my code:

```
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
      $nim = $_POST["nim"]; $nama = $_POST["nama"]; $jurusan = $_POST["jurusan"];
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "belajar");
      $query ="UPDATE 'mahasiswa' SET nama = '".$nama."', jurusan = '".$jurusan."' WHERE nim = ".$nim."";
      if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
          echo "Record updated successfully";
          } else {
          echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This, **Do not use single quotes in table name,**

```
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
      $nim = $_POST["nim"]; $nama = $_POST["nama"]; $jurusan = $_POST["jurusan"];
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "jimlyas", "shafira", "belajar");
      $query ="UPDATE `mahasiswa` SET nama = '".$nama."', jurusan = '".$jurusan."' WHERE nim = '".$nim."' ";
      if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
          echo "Record updated successfully";
          } else {
          echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like.

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "belajar");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// update part
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
  $nim = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["nim"]); 
  $nama = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["nama"]); 
  $jurusan = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["jurusan"]);
  $query ="UPDATE mahasiswa SET nama = '$nama', jurusan = '$jurusan' WHERE nim = '$nim'";
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
      echo "Record updated successfully";
  } else {
      echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```